# Windows 10 doesn't remember the applications I launch from "run"

Tags: windows, windows-10

Not sure what I did: since yesterday when I launch for example `Notepad` from the <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> "Run", after closing it, when doing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> again, Notepad isn't there whereas before Windows remembered every applications I launched from there (not sure how to explain this better sorry).

Any idea why Windows is now incapable of remembering anything?

EDIT: actually in Firefox when typing URL that are in favorites, Firefox doesn't remember them anymore either. It's like everything on my computer became incapable of remembering anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: Someone might have changed your privacy scattered settings in Windows and Firefox.

Solution: Launch the Settings app (from the start menu, type `Settings`) and pick Personalisation.

OR right click an empty space on your desktop and pick `Personalise`.

From the left, pick Start. Turn on `Show most used apps`. This will keep a history record of programmes in Run and Start, but not Firefox.

To fix your problem with Firefox, type in the location bar in Firefox `about:preferences#privacy`. From the Location bar section on that page, tick the items that suit your needs (History, Bookmarks, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Left click on Start Menu
2. Click on Settings
3. Type in "Recent " in **Find a Setting**
4. Select **"Show Recently added apps in Start"**
5. Turn on **"Show recently added apps"**

Comment: I don't have a "settings" in start menu, left or right click!

Comment: On Left Click, I have "File Explorer", "Settings", "Power" and "All Apps" oin the bottom left.  What do you see ?